# How to get listitem counts via rest api

Tags: sharepoint-rest-api, list-item

I tried the below to get all item count of a list but it doesn't work

```
/_api/Web/Lists/getByTitle('<list title>')?$select=ItemCount,Items&$expand=Items
```

Any ideas how i can get an itemcount as well as retrieving the fields in my select?
How can i also retrieve itemCount with filtering?

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You could use the rest API below as mentioned.

```
/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('<list title>')/ItemCount
```

You will get item count of any list or library

you have one more option to retrieve both

You could construct the following query to return items and items count:

```
/_api/Web/Lists/getByTitle('<list title>')?$select=ItemCount,Items&$expand=Items
```

In success function you could write the below code to get

```
 var itemsCount = data.d.ItemCount;
    var items = data.d.Items.results;
```

Comment: Thanks Suresh but your recommendation doesn't seem to work

Comment: I have implemented the above query in my solution which is working for me to retrieve the list items and item count.
do you want list items of fields ?

Comment: I wanted to find the item count in a list with more than 5000 items, and this code works for me.

Comment: Is there a way to pass $filter to this count query? I need to get the total count of a filtered dataset. I cannot use dataset.length because I'm using skip & top (for paging) and needs to get the total count in a separate query.

Comment: No. You cannot apply filter on this

Answer (score 5):

It is better to use:

```
"/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('<list title>')/ItemCount"
```

instead of:

```
"/_api/Web/Lists/GetByTitle('<list title>')/Items"
```

because `"/ItemCount"` is faster with quick response.

Answer (score 0):

Use REST API to get items you need, then get no.of items using `data.d.results.length`.

```
function getItems(url) {    
    return $.ajax({
        url: _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + url,
        type: "GET",
        headers: {
            "accept": "application/json;odata=verbose",
        }
    });
}

getItems( "/_api/Web/Lists/GetByTitle('<list title>')/Items" ).done(function(data){

    var numofItems = data.d.results.length;
     data.d.results.forEach(function(item){ 
        console.log( item.ID);
     });
});
```

Comment: ItemCount worked for us. Thank you very much! We didn't use GetItems due to the limit on the number of items that can be returned at once and it had a quicker response.

Comment: [Ryan Exner] is correct.   If you have more items than the OData limit, the list that is returned will not be complete.  [docs here](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/sp-add-ins/working-with-lists-and-list-items-with-rest#working-with-list-items-by-using-rest)  The default limit seems to be 100 items.

Comment: True, there is the possibility of OData limit. `/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('<list title>')/ItemCount` is the correct way, so @Suresh Bolineni answer better.

Comment: ItemCount is tricky as it will return anumber of all items, also those to which user in context doesn't have access to

Comment: Is there a way to pass $filter to this count query? I need to get the total count of a filtered dataset. I cannot use dataset.length because I'm using skip & top (for paging) and needs to get the total count in a separate query.

Comment: This answer is wrong if the response is paginated. Use `/ItemCount` instead.

Answer (score 0):

August 2023:

I am using 0365 SharePoint and **this did NOT** work for me:

```
"/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('<list title>')/ItemCount"
```

**but this did**:

```
"/_api/lists/getbytitle('<list title>')/ItemCount"
```

***Note the removal of `web/`*** This makes a very fast call and doesn't abuse bandwidth by pulling rows (even select=Id) for no reason and bypasses the REST/oData limits.

Here is what I use. If you do not want to use `odata=verbose` in the headers you will want to return `data.value` vs `data.d.ItemCount`.

```
/**
 Gets list item count avoids oData limits
 @date      08/21/2023
 @param     {string}    listname  Name of the list.
 @param     {callback}  success   The success callback
 @param     {callback}  failure   The failure callback
 */
getListItemCount(listname, success, failure) {
    var url = common.myWebUrl() + "/_api/lists/getbytitle('" + listname + "')/ItemCount";

    $.ajax({
        url: url,
        async: this.useAsync,
        method: "GET",
        headers: { "Accept": "application/json; odata=verbose" },
        success: function (data) {
            success(data.d.ItemCount); 
        },
        error: function (data) {
            failure(data);
        }
    });

}
```

hth

Also, I use a common file for my webUrls based on the project. It's always something like the this:

```
    const webUrl = window.myContext["webAbsoluteUrl"]; //window.webPartContext.pageContext.web.absoluteUrl;
    return webUrl;
```